# Relative URL to images in another folder accessed inside a JS file

Tags: relative-path

I have this Wordpress plugin file structure with "myfolder" as the main folder. There is another subfolder inside this main folder named as "resources". Inside this resources folder contains two subfolders: a) JS  b.) images

Inside images folder I have one image "myimage.png".
Inside JS file, I have a script named "myscript.js".

I would like to access the image "myimage.png" in images folder inside my javascript file "myscript.js".

I have tried the following but it does not work(does not resolve):

```
<img src="../images/myimage.png">
<img src="images/myimage.png">
<img src="resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="../resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="myfolder/resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="../myfolder/resources/images/myimage.png">
```

Of course the absolute URL path works but I want this application to work with other sites so coding the absolute URL path is not a feasible solution.

I know that Wordpress also has this magic function:

```
$myicons= plugins_url('resources/images/myimage.png', __FILE__ );
```

But that will work only inside the PHP plugin file and I'm accessing the image inside a JS file. Any ideas how to make this work without rearranging the current file structure? Is there a JS function equivalent of "plugins_url" in Wordpress? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78521/plugin-relative-url-to-images-in-another-folder-accessed-inside-a-js-file

The trick is to use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script then pass the image path as object and access it in your JS code.